# How to fix: the options [servers] is not supported the options [caseTranslate] is not supported

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My objective is to simply insert a message into database from a form post.

I have tried the following code without using any framework.

```
const http = require('http');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var qs = require('querystring');
var url = require('url');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
var messages = "";

client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("mydb").collection("messages");
  console.log('Connected successfully to database server');
  collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    messages += "<table border='1'><tr><th>Messages</th></tr>"
    for (var x in docs) {
      messages += "<tr><td>" + docs[x].message + "</td></tr>";
    }
    messages += "</table>"
  });
});

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.write(`
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <body>
      ${messages}
      <form action="/" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="message" />
          <button>Insert</button>
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>`);
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
      body += data;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
      var post = qs.parse(body);
      client.connect(err => {
        const collection = client.db("mydb").collection("messages");
        collection.insertOne(post, function (err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 document inserted");
        })
      });
    });
    res.end();
  }
  res.end();
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Now after running and submitting a form post although the document get inserted but i get error "the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported" in console. Please assist me what is the proper way to achieve the goal or any workaround. Thanks.